# Any way to award a second +100 bounty to a second answer to the same question?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I've awarded a `+100` bounty to [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20659/12102). but there is a [second answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/20690/12102) that uses a different approach to the derivation that I find equally helpful, and I would like to award a second `+100`. When I click the *start a bounty* button, the lowest available number is `+200`.

A work-around would be to "borrow" some, but I'm asking here if there is a way within the stackexchange system to do this.

Further, is there an existing rationale for blocking any value below 200, or is it just a **bufeature**? (a bug retroactively defined as a feature)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subsequent bounties have to go up in value. It seems people were taking advantage of the system. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64826/155668 for the details.

Comment: Wow, 2010! I haven't ever been linked to something that old before. I wonder if the current solution is still the best, considering seven years of experience and development of SE. But I don't wonder nearly enough to raise the question. Thanks for the speedy reply and history lesson!